# What's wrong with this scanf()?

Tags: c, char, scanf

Am I using scanf() in some wrong way?

```
char *input;
scanf("%s", input);
printf("%s\n", input);
```

This fails at the run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *input;
```

This is a pointer. It doesn't point to any memory.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //char *input;
    char input[128];
    memset(input, 0 ,sizeof(input));
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Declaring a `char *` only creates a pointer, it does not allocate any memory for the string. You need to allocate memory for input. You can do that dynamically via `malloc` (and `free` when done) or you can declare an array of static size like `char input[100]`.

Comment: how can I use malloc() if i don't know the size of my string beforehand?

Comment: You need to assume some maximum size. Or if maximum size assumption is not possible then you can read chunk-by-chunk in a loop, e.g. read chunk of 1000 characters and append it to a buffer, then read next chunk of 1000 more characters and go on like this until you reach the end.

Comment: Which is why `scanf()` is not safe, at least traditionally. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) discusses some methods to overcome this.

Comment: @n3rd4n1, yes input without bound checking is risky. It's the same reason that `fgets` is more preferable to `gets`.

Comment: @taskinoor If I could do what you just said, I would not be asking such a basic question here.

Comment: @BlueFlame, to input a string you need to allocate memory. That's how C works. There is no way to bypass that. In many situations assuming a max size is enough and you can declare array with static size. But if that is not enough for your situation then you have to choose more sophisticated solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace `char *input;` with `char input[1024] = {0};`

you should ensure the parameter you pass to scanf points to a buffer which could hold your input